# Single word for someone who does not eat mammal's meat

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single descriptor for someone who eats anything (chicken, fish, insects, veggie burger,...) but just not any mammals (from the conviction that they are "to close to us" to serve as food).  Not a compound something like pollo-pesco-ovo-etc-arian, but a single word?

Comment: Did you mean '**too** close to us'?

Comment: yes, sorry!  "too close" in the sense all mammals descend from a common ancestor so it comes close to cannibalism to eat mammals

Comment: by the way, what would be the ethymology of the word "mafist" - I can't really recongnize any root.

Comment: I've become a non mammal eater about 6 months ago.It really is frustrating not having an official term for this lifestyle. Could not find Mafist in any dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a single descriptor for someone who eats anything (chicken, fish, insects, veggie burger,...) but just not any mammals

Someone who does not eat mammals'meat is called **mafist**. Mafists are sometimes called pesco-pollo-tarians.

[Pescetarian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescetarianism) is someone who does not eat meat but eats fish.

> **Pescetarians** eat the meat of fish and other non-mammalian sea creatures, but not of birds or reptiles, nor of mammals. **Mafists** avoid only the meat of mammals. They eat poultry and fish. (I guess they might also eat reptiles. [[**Yahoo Answers**]](http://www.answers.yahoo.com/amp/qna/20101220184717AAID2Yh)

Also read:
[**Mafism**](https://www.scribd.com/doc/125288937/Mafism-A-Reasonable-Rational-Alternative-to-Vegetarianism) — Scribd

Comment: Gee, I always thought they were pesky politicians.

Comment: @HotLicks Wow, I always thought they were pesky Presbyterians.

Answer (score 0):

**Mafism** or **mafist** seems to be a correct answer, since the you asked for a single word. However, this word doesn't seem to be in common use; it doesn't seem to appear in any dictionary, doesn't have any Google Trends data. I have never heard it before now. So if you choose to use this word you will likely have to clarify the meaning.

What I have heard many people say is that they **don't eat red meat**. This isn't one word, but it commonly used. **Red meat** is a synonym for mammal meat, while **white meat** is used for the meat of other animals, usually fish and birds.

Also there are many different reasons one might choose a certain diet such as this or vegetarianism. Not wanting to eat something that is "too similar to us" is a possible reason, but health reasons or ecological reasons are common.

Comment: This is a very sensible answer. Single word “labels” often do more harm than good.

Comment: "White meat" is ambiguous, because in common usage it includes pork.